# change font color if the cell is empty in a variable sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i had have a lot of probleme with the code.

i want to have something who check if the cell is empty (if it is empty) set font in red

i only (small succes but already great for me T.T ) manage to have a way to selecte the variable range.

but i don't  what to do after.

````
function test10() { 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var valeur = 'C60'
 var cible = ss.getSheetByName('Kopie von Loyers');
 var valeurH = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(valeur).getValue()
 var piou = cible.getRange(2, valeurH, 50, 1);
 var piou2 = piou.getA1Notation() //get the rang in a1notation
 var piou3 = cible.getRange(piou2)
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

i have to get the value in C60  because  it has to check the date in the purpose to have a range who automaticly change according the date. (i'm sur that their is a way to have this in a script but to difficult at my level)

i "juste" (seems to be easy at the begginning  but not anymore)  want that in range (2, valeurH, 50, 1) when a cell is empty the color of the font become red

i have this thing who actually work. i know it is messy and certainly too munch line who are useless im my situation

````
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var valeur = 'C60'
  var cible = ss.getSheetByName('Kopie von Loyers');
  var valeurH = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(valeur).getValue()
  var piou = cible.getRange(2, valeurH, 50, 1);
  var piou2 = piou.getA1Notation()
  var piou3 = cible.getRange(piou2)
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getDataRange().setBackground(null);  // I'm not sure whether you want this line.
  
  // 1. Retrieve values from the Spreadsheet.
  var range = sheet.getRange(piou2);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var test3 = range.getValue()
  // 2. Create an array including the color codes.
    var colors = values.map(r => {
    var length = r.length;
    if (r.every(e => e.toString() == "500")) {
      return Array(length).fill();
    } else if (r.splice(0, 7).every(e => e.toString() == "")) {
      return Array(length - 1).fill().concat("#ff0000");
    }
    return Array(length).fill();
  });

  
  // 3. Set the font colors using the created array.
  range.setFontColors(colors);
}```
````